# how to compute "begin" and "endindex" for time series in the hydrograph function. R

Tags: r, plot

**The following function:**

```
hydrograph(df, streamflow = df$`Q (m3/s)` , timeSeries = df$`Sampling time`,
           precip = df$`Rainfall mm`, begin = 1,
           endindex = length(streamflow), P.units = "mm", S.units = "m3/s",
           stream.label = "Streamflow")
```

**results into:**
[image: Hydrograph]

This function allows me to plot certain time ranges using **begin** and **endindex**. My problem is that I want to plot from the ***13/07/2021 00:15:00*** to ***27/07/2021 18:00:00*** (this date's range is the length of the streamflow data) and I don't seem to get it right. I have tried.
a) **endindex = length(streamflow)**
b) **begin = "13/07/2021 00:15:00"**, **endindex = "27/07/2021 18:00:00"**

Comment: You should provide [data and libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using the [tidyverse](https://www.tidyverse.org/) framework, you can pre-filter your stream before passing it to the plotting function:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(EcoHydRology)
df |>
   filter(`Sampling time` >= as.Date("13/07/2021 00:15:00"),
          `Sampling time` <= as.Date("27/07/2021 18:00:00")) |> 
   with(hydrograph(streamflow = `Q (m3/s)` , 
                   timeSeries = `Sampling time`,
                   precip = `Rainfall mm`, 
                   P.units = "mm", 
                   S.units = "m3/s",
                   stream.label = "Streamflow")
```